# flash messaging not appearing in flask

Tags: python, flash, flask

When i logged in flash message is not displayed.How can i fix it ?

My login def is below

```
@app.route("/login",methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
  form=LoginForm(request.form)
      if request.method=="POST":
        username=form.username.data
        password_entered=form.password.data

cursor=mysql.connection.cursor()
sorgu="Select * From users where username = %s"
result=cursor.execute(sorgu,(username,))
if result>0:
  data=cursor.fetchone() 
  real_password=data["password"]
  if sha256_crypt.verify(password_entered,real_password):
      flash("Başarıyla giriş yaptınız...","info")
      session["logged_in"]=True
      session["username"]=username
      return redirect(url_for("index"))
  else:
      flash(("wrong password","warning"))
      return redirect(url_for("login"))

else:
  flash("this username is not avaible","warning")
  return render_template("login.html",form=form)
```

i dont know why it is not working.When logged in redirect url function is working but flash message does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in one argument (a tuple) instead of two.

Change `flash(("wrong password","warning"))` to `flash("wrong password","warning")`